# Unable to install python extension on code-server

Tags: vscode-extensions, code-server

I am install vscode using the below commands on ubuntu base image and trying to install python extension and it gets an error.

```
ARG IDE_HOME="/opt"
ARG CODE_SERVER_VERSION="v3.11.1"
ARG CODE_SERVER_FILE="code-server-3.11.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz"
WORKDIR $IDE_HOME/code-server/
RUN wget -qO- https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/${CODE_SERVER_VERSION}/${CODE_SERVER_FILE} | tar zxvf - --strip-components=1
ENV PATH=$IDE_HOME/code-server/bin:$PATH
RUN code-server --install-extension ms-python.python
```

Error:

```
    [2022-03-24T06:01:24.303Z] info  Wrote default config file to ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
Installing extensions...
Server returned 404
[2022-03-24T06:01:29.030Z] error vscode Failed Installing Extensions: ms-python.python
[2022-03-24T06:01:29.032Z] error vscode Error: Failed Installing Extensions: ms-python.python
    at L.installExtensions (/opt/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/entry.js:19:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async /opt/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/entry.js:41:86115
    at async Object.T [as main] (/opt/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/entry.js:41:89502)
    at async process.<anonymous> (/opt/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/entry.js:41:99068)
The command '/bin/sh -c code-server --install-extension ms-python.python' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Also have the same issue. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I downloaded the actual extensions and use the vsix file to install. e..g 
* jupyter: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-toolsai/vsextensions/jupyter/2021.6.832593372/vspackage
* python: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/2021.5.926500501

`RUN code-server --install-extension /opt/code-server/extensions/ms-python-release.vsix`

Comment: I also updated to the later version of code server. That was my fix.

Comment: ah with later version, I was getting error on certificate/credentials issue